# Using AET62 BSAPILoader.dll receiving UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using an NFC Reader AET62 in which I am trying to use the fingerprint authentication `BSAPILoader.dll` library in eclipse for Java. The error I am receiving is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: FingerprintScanner.FingerprintImage.ABSInitialize()I
    at FingerprintScanner.FingerprintImage.ABSInitialize(Native Method)
    at FingerprintScanner.FingerprintImage.jABSInitialize(FingerprintImage.java:15)
    at Main.SecurityConfigAndControlsMain.main(SecurityConfigAndControlsMain.java:16)
```

The `BSAPILoader.dll` is in the dll included with the SDK and it specifies that it can be used through  `System.loadLibrary("BSAPILoader");` and then by using for example `private native int ABSInitialize();`

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you configure the location of the dll to the library? Also what happens if you call `System.loadLibrary("BSAPILoader")`? Does it throw `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: Thanks, No System.loadLibrary("BSAPILoader") does not which is what is really confusing me. I have added the dll to the environment Path variable for the system. I have place the dll in the system32 directory.

Comment: You should edit such information directly into the question, not everybody reads the comments. There is an "edit" link below the question.